# C/C++ Finding pointers

Tags: c++, c, memory, pointers, architecture

I've recently completed a basic memory scanner, and like all people that have ever done this... I've realised that scanning for values every time a program starts is a pain!

It would be useful to work out the base pointers for these values so that they can be hard coded into a application. To work out how to do this I created this short console app using visual c++ for my "target".

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    unsigned int * Pointer1;
    Pointer1 = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    char s[20];
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"(Pid:"<<GetCurrentProcessId()<<") Please enter a value to be stored in memory (type 'q' to exit): \n";
        std::cin>>s;
        std::cout<<"\n";
        if(s[0] =='q')
        {
            break;
        }
        *Pointer1 = str2int(s);
        std::cout<<"Value:"<<*Pointer1<<" addr:0x"<<Pointer1<<"\n";
    }
    free(Pointer1);

return 0;
}
```

I then used this app in accordance with my memory scanner to work out the addresses of the pointer and the memory address the pointer points to. I did this a few times to collate the bellow data. (Paste using '|' as delimiter into excel)

```
pid |P Hex|P Val|PHx to Dec|M Hex|M Val|MHx To Dec
7028|002afcfc|216032|2817276|00034BE0|10|216032
6312|0032fa70|4541408|3340912|00454BE0|20|4541408
1512|0043fb1c|3242304|4455196|00317940|30|3242304
8140|0036f9fc|1997096|3602940|001E7928|30|1997096
```

However I cant work out a reliable way of calculating what memory address the pointer will be, what methods/calculations could I perform to do this? I'm aware that the more life like example of pointer chains exists however this seemed like a good starting point before making it harder.

Comment: Why exactly is this tagged [tag:c] and [tag:c++]?

Comment: @bitmask: Because the code is a ghastly hybrid of the two languages.

Comment: Note that systems will often perform address space randomization to try to make certain you won't get the same addresses on different runs (a security measure).

Answer (score 4):

The memory address is whatever `malloc` returns.  There is no reliable way of calculating what it will return.  It all depends on how your `malloc` library works, what virtual address ranges it is given by the OS (via `sbrk` or `mmap` or others), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to predict the address that will be returned from `malloc`.

It doesn't matter.

If you **could** predict what would be returned from `malloc`, `malloc` wouldn't need to return anything.

In practice, it never matters what address is returned from malloc, other than `NULL`.  A call to malloc implies that you need a number of bytes of memory.  And malloc will give you that.  You got what you needed.

Conversely, if you could determine what addresses would be returned from malloc, you would never need to call malloc.  You could just use the addresses you predicted.

**Put simply, `malloc` exists because it is not trivial to predict what memory might be available.**